# Not able to get display error Message

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am not able to display error message on VF page

My code :

```
VF page 
<apex:page contr
<apex:pageMessages />
```

controller

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error'));
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `<apex:message/>` element to your Visualforce page to display Apex page messages like so:

```
<apex:page controller="VFPagecontroller">
  <apex:message/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulties with `<apex:message/>`. If that doesn't work, you  may try the following.

Include `<apex:pageMessages />` in your VF page as below:

```
<apex:page controller="Yourcontroller">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [apex:pageMessage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_outputText.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) you are missing one of mandatory fields - **severity**.

As for me here is my code:

Page:

```
<apex:page >

    <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!(errorMessage != null)}" summary="{!errorMessage}" severity="warning" strength="2" />


    <apex:form >
```

Controller:

> public String errorMessage {get;set;}
>
> if(error) { errorMessage = 'Some error text goes here'; }

Answer (score 0):

```
if(opp.stagename=='closed won'&& opp.close_date__c==null) {
  ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.info, 'please select closed date.');
  pexPages.addMessage(msg);

}
```